# prevent google map from moving up/down after fit bounds ios sdk

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, zooming

I am working on an app where I am showing `google map` with 3 markers

```
1 user
2 hotel
3 airport
```

I added code for `fit bounds` and the map zoomed out to show all markers and it's working as expected, but as soon as user's location changes the map moves it's location and after few steps the `hotel/airport marker` is not visible in the `map`. I want to display all the `markers` every time even if user moves.I don't want to use fit bounds again and again for this, What could be the solution for this ?

Comment: I think that `fitBounds` is the best option. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: it will animate the map while I don't want any kind of animation

Comment: I want the map should stays the same even if user is moving. isn't it possible to stop map from moving ?

Comment: You could try disabling [Map gestures](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/controls#map_gestures) after fitBounds is done loading the map. You can disable `scrollGestures`, `zoomGestures`, `tiltGestures`, `rotateGestures`. You can disable the default gestures on the map by setting properties of the `GMSUISettings` class, which is available as a property of the `GMSMapView`. The following gestures can be enabled and disabled programmatically. Note that disabling the gesture will not limit programmatic access to the camera settings.